# Remove Leaflet minicharts

Tags: javascript, charts, leaflet

I've created piecharts with the **Leaflet.minicharts.js** plugin. 
It works fine to add the charts. 
But I can't remove them anymore.
I tried to remove each chart separately with `map.removeLayer(chart[i])`.
And I also tried to put all charts together in a LayerGroup and then use the function `map.removeLayer(LayerGroup)` and with `layergorup.clearLayers()`. When I call the function `map.hasLayer(layer)`, it returns `false`. So, everything as expected. But the charts are still visible on the map.
Here a simple example with a barchart, which I try to remove with a button-click.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-wcw6ts8Anuw10Mzh9Ytw4pylW8+NAD4ch3lqm9lzAsTxg0GFeJgoAtxuCLREZSC5lUXdVyo/7yfsqFjQ4S+aKw=="
   crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-mNqn2Wg7tSToJhvHcqfzLMU6J4mkOImSPTxVZAdo+lcPlk+GhZmYgACEe0x35K7YzW1zJ7XyJV/TT1MrdXvMcA=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.minichart/dist/leaflet.minichart.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <style type="text/css">
        #mapid { height: 480px; }
        #butt {color:black;position: absolute;padding:2em;top:50%; left:50%;}
    </style>

    <div id="mapid"></div>
    <button id="butt" onclick="vanish();">Remove Chart!</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = L.map('mapid').setView([50, 9], 14);
        var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        }).addTo( map );

        var center = [50, 9];
        function fakeData() {           
          return [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];
        }        

        var myBarChart = L.minichart(center, {data: fakeData()});
        map.addLayer(myBarChart);


        function vanish(e) {
            console.log(map.hasLayer(myBarChart));
            map.removeLayer(myBarChart);
            console.log(map.hasLayer(myBarChart));
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the same problem. What i did is I wrote a function where i can loop through the layer-group to find if the Layer-group contains a layer with the property "_chart". If so, remove that layer. The loop continues till it removes all the layers with that property. Here is the code what i wrote.

```
for(var i = 0; i<Object.keys(lyrGrp._layers).length;i++){

    if(lyrGrp._layers[Object.keys(lyrGrp._layers)[i]]._chart)
      {
       lyrGrp._layers[Object.keys(lyrGrp._layers)[i]]._chart.remove()
      } 

 }
```

Hope it is useful.